# Change color to a single point in plotly scatter 3D

Tags: plotly-python, scatter3d

I made a plotly 3D scatter:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(data, x = x, y = y, z = z, color=data['A'],
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Spectral_r,
                    color_continuous_midpoint= 0,
                    hover_data=(['B','C']))
```

And added another single point:

```
fig.add_scatter3d(x = [0], y= [0], z=[0], mode='markers', color='white')
```

However, `color = 'white'`, does not work.
 `ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatter3d: 'color'`
Any idea on how I can change the color of that single point?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work ok:

```
fig.add_scatter3d(x = [0], y= [0], z=[0], mode='markers',marker=dict(color='white'),showlegend=False)
```

or

```
fig.add_scatter3d(x = [0], y= [0], z=[0], mode ='markers',marker_color='white',showlegend=False)
```